# javascript jsdoc namespace class static method

Tags: javascript, class, static, namespaces, jsdoc

I'm trying to use jsDoc on my js code in which I want to define:
 - A Namespace.
 - A Class.
 - A Static Method.
Note that the code does exactly what I expect at runtime, but I have problems to getting started with jsDoc, so I question myself if code is correct...

```
/** @namespace
 * @name myNamespace
 * @description myNamespace description.
 */
if (typeof (myNamespace) == "undefined") myNamespace = { };

/** @class 
 * @name myClass
 * @description myClass description.
 * @memberof myNamespace
 * @inner
 */
myNamespace.myClass = function () { };

/** @method
 * @name myStaticMethod
 * @description myStaticMethod description.
 * @param {String} myParam. Required. myParam description.
 * @return myReturnValue description.
 * @remarks remarks description.
 * @memberof myNamespace.myClass
 * @inner
 */
myNamespace.myClass.myStaticMethod = function (myParam) {
    var myReturnValue = myParam;
    return myReturnValue;
};
```

When I generate with jsDoc I see in the index:
- Correct myNamespace definition.
- Correct myClass definition.
When I go inside myClass I cannot see myStaticMethod...
myStaticMethod is not present anywhere.
My JS is coded correctly?
If is correctly coded... Is the comments correctly written?
What's wrong?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Side note: `typeof` is an operator, not a function; there's no need for parens around the value, for the same reason you can just write `1 + 2` rather than `(1) + (2)` and `new ClassName()` rather than `new (ClassName())`.

Comment: Separately, your code relies on [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) to create `myNamespace`. The better way is: `var myNamespace;` (which has no effect at all if it already exists) followed by your `typeof` test.

Comment: Thanks I'll take in mind and will try to refactor the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use [`@name`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-name.html), you need to tell JsDoc what the member is; using `@name` tells JsDoc to **completely** ignore context.

In your case, I think you need to add [`@static`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-static.html) (you already have [`@memberof`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html), so that's good).

Answer (score 2):

T.J. Crowder was right, I cannot vote becouse I'm young in community, this is the corrected code comments for jsDoc if someone need:

```
/** @namespace
 * @name myNamespace
 * @description myNamespace description.
 */
if (typeof (myNamespace) == "undefined") myNamespace = { };

/** @class 
 * @name myNamespace.myClass
 * @description myClass description.
 * @memberof myNamespace
 * @inner
 */
myNamespace.myClass = function () { };

/** @function
 * @static
 * @name myNamespace.myClass.myStaticMethod
 * @description myStaticMethod description.
 * @param {String} myParam. Required. myParam description.
 * @return myReturnValue description.
 * @remarks remarks description.
 * @memberof myNamespace.myClass
 * @inner
 */

myNamespace.myClass.myStaticMethod = function (myParam) {
    var myReturnValue = myParam;
    return myReturnValue;
};
```